# Iterating multiple $_POST arrays

Tags: php, arrays, input, multidimensional-array

I have the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td width="60%">
        <dl>
            <dt>Full Name</dt>
            <dd>
                <input name="fullname[]" type="text" class="txt w90" id="fullname[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </td>
    <td width="30%">
        <dl>
            <dt>Job Title</dt>
            <dd>
                <input name="job_title[]" type="text" class="txt w90" id="job_title[]" value="<?php echo $value2; ?>" />
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Lets assume that I have several rows of the above code. How do I iterate and get the value for arrays `$_POST['fullname']` and `$_POST['job_title']`?

Answer (score 10):

It's just an array:

```
foreach ($_POST['fullname'] as $name) {
    echo $name."\n";
}
```

If the problem is you want to iterate over the two arrays in parallel simply use one of them to get the indexes:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['fullname']); $i++) {
    echo $_POST['fullname'][$i]."\n";
    echo $_POST['job_title'][$i]."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I deleted this earlier since it was pretty close to Vinko's answer.

```
for ($i = 0, $t = count($_POST['fullname']); $i < $t; $i++) {
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'][$i];
    $job_title = $_POST['job_title'][$i];
    echo "$fullname $job_title \n";
}
```

With original index not numerical from 0 - N-1

```
$range = array_keys($_POST['fullname']);
foreach ($range as $key) {
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'][$key];
    $job_title = $_POST['job_title'][$key];
    echo "$fullname $job_title \n";
}
```

This is just for general info. With SPL DualIterator you can make something like:

```
$dualIt = new DualIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['fullname']), new ArrayIterator($_POST['job_title']));

while($dualIt->valid()) {
    list($fullname, $job_title) = $dualIt->current();
    echo "$fullname $job_title \n";
    $dualIt->next();
}
```

Comment: And what would the benefit of the DualIterator be?

Comment: Its similar to every other Iterator in SPL, so for those who use Iterators its familiar. Its also similar for those used to Java I guess. But I think they should have at least make a MultiIterator instead of a limited DualIterator.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're trying to solve, is getting a pair of values from $_POST['fullname'][] and $_POST['jobtitle'][] which have same index.

```
for ($i = 0, $rowcount = count($_POST['fullname']); $i < $rowcount; $i++)
{
    $name = $_POST['fullname'][$i]; // get name
    $job  = $_POST['jobtitle'][$i]; // get jobtitle
}
```

Comment: This answer is the same as OIS' answer above.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it after I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have 2 arrays that you basically wish to iterate over in parallel.

Something like the below may work for you.  Instead of `$a1`, and `$a2` you would use `$_POST['fullname']` and `$_POST['jobtitle']`.

```
<?php
$a1=array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
$a2=array('1','2','3','4','5','6');

// reset array pointers    
reset($a1); reset($a2);
while (TRUE)
{
  // get current item
  $item1=current($a1);
  $item2=current($a2);
  // break if we have reached the end of both arrays
  if ($item1===FALSE and $item2===FALSE) break;  
  print $item1.' '. $item2.PHP_EOL;
  // move to the next items
  next($a1); next($a2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Vinko and OIS' answers are excellent (I upticked OIS'). But, if you are always printing 5 copies of the text fields, you can always just name each field specifically:

```
<?php $i=0; while($i < 5) { ?><tr>
    ...
    <input name="fullname[<?php echo $i; ?>]" type="text" class="txt w90" id="fullname[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
```

Comment: this will produce the same result as not naming them.

Comment: Not exactly. The user could enter data in name[1] and job[3] and hit submit. The empty arrays will return both as name[0] and job[0]. Mine will not. (I don't know how helpful that makes mine though. :-) )